# Twitter oembed for timelines?

Tags: php, twitter, oembed

Hi I use the following code to embed tweets but I am wondering if there is away as simple as the following to embed user profiles, I can't seem to find it on dev.twitter.com they keep taking me to make a widget. which is what I want to do but I want them to do it on request of the PHP

Currently i use something like this. But as you can see from below it only gets the status and not the timeline of the user.

```
$status = file_get_contents("https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j]);
$stats = json_decode($status);
//$string = "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/oembed.json?url=".$links[$j];
if(isset($stats->errors))
{ 

}
else 
  $string=str_replace($links[$j],'<a href="'.$links[$j].'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">'.$links[$j].'</a>',$string).$stats->html;
}
```

Comment: According to [this discussion](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/17613) it's not possible without building the html yourself with API data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the html of users timeline, like you are getting it for status.

There is no end point with oembed available for users profile.

But you can easily build it yourself by following these steps.

- Register an application
- Get the API keys and access token
- Use some library for PHP from these listed in this page [Twitter Libraries](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries), I would prefer going with the [abraham's library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth)
- Get the user details by making request to this URL:
  `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=[screen_name]`
  *`*Note: Twitter API v1 is deprecated so use API v1.1 for making requests`*
- Fetch the JSON response and render it in your html code